# How to specify SAML encryption certificate in ruby-saml?

Tags: saml-2.0, ruby-saml

The ruby-saml gem supports adding certificate and private-key info to Service Provider's metadata, but as far as I can tell, that configures only signing certificate, but not encryption one. Here's what I do:

```
settings.certificate = "---- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----..."
settings.private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----..."
```

which results in the following XML section added to Service Provider's metadata:

```
<md:KeyDescriptor use='signing'>
      <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>
CERTIFICATE IS HERE GSDk3tShjl4yhShj4Hr....
          </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
```

But how do I configure ruby-saml to add a similar section for `use='encryption'` in addition to `use='signing'`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, You are not able to send the SAMLResponse in the encrypted form. If that is the case, when you are building the SAML response, send one more parameter

```
saml_response = encode_response( :encryption => encryption_opts())

def encryption_opts: 
return {
      cert: saml_request.service_provider.cert,
      block_encryption: 'aes256-cbc',
      key_transport: 'rsa-oaep-mgf1p'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I'm not sure I understand where would this code fit. I use `saml_config_hash = OneLogin::RubySaml::IdpMetadataParser.new.parse_to_hash(idp_metadata_file)` to parse the SAML metadata file provided by the identity provider, and add to the resulting hash options, such as:
`saml_config_hash.merge(
certificate: "--- BEGIN CERTIFICATE---...",
private_key: "--- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---"
)`

Answer (score 0):

The gem's documentation shows that you can support multiple certificates by assigning a hash.
e.g:

```rb
@settings.idp_cert_multi = {
  :signing => [],
  :encryption => []
}
```

I have not tested this.

See
https://github.com/SAML-Toolkits/ruby-saml#handling-multiple-idp-certificates